# UINavigationBar color is faded, and not the correct color

Tags: swift

I'm trying to change the background color of my UINavigationBar to a custom UIColor, however the displayed color is a default faded green color. I believe that the issue is the fact that my custom UIColor is being rendered with sRGB since I'm using iOS10, however I don't know how to change the default color scale. I tried finding my solution in the Apple Developer Guide, but I was unable to find a solution. Could you guys please point me in the right direction?

Your help / input is very much appreciated.

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 237/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Color I want:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Actual Color (blocked out details of my app):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue.

Instead of using backgroundColor, I used barTintColor.

Code:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 237/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```